# Open cmd from java

Tags: java

So I want to open cmd though java with this code

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class mainer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
           Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start");
           System.out.println("ok");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this error when I execute it

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at mainer.main(mainer.java:6)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid  Win32 application
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

and the funny thing is that it worked 2 days ago and now it gives me this strange error

Comment: I am using 32 bit OS and 32 bit java....your code executed successfully in my machine... The problem may with   OS and java mismatch(32 bit and 64)

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","start"});
```

To learn more about the [start](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx), type `help start` at command prompt.

Comment: 'Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","start"});'    
gives the same error + sorry I am new to the site and I find difficulties marking test as code

Comment: Check @fabian-barney answer. Probably you are using 32-Bit Java on a x64 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your PATH variable doesn't have path to cmd.exe in it so better try this.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class mainer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
           Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{System.getenv().get("SystemRoot")+"/cmd.exe", "/c", "start"});
           System.out.println("ok");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to start 64-bit `cmd.exe` from 32-bit JRE.

Try to execute `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` instead which is 32-bit.